# PHP Pthreads unknown class Thread

Tags: php, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am using:

- PHP 5.5.8
- Apache 2.2.22
- Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Trying to install PHP module Pthreads, recompilled, everything works fine using CLI, but when I try to start a new thread, it gives me error:

```
[Mon Jan 13 12:24:38 2014]  Script:  '/var/www/index.php'
/home/jd/Downloads/php-5.5.8/Zend/zend_hash.c(450) :  Freeing 0x7F4C302051C8 (128         bytes), script=/var/www/index.php
[Mon Jan 13 12:24:38 2014]  Script:  '/var/www/index.php'
/home/jd/Downloads/php-5.5.8/Zend/zend_language_parser.c(5419) :  Freeing 0x7F4C300F9590  (72 bytes), script=/var/www/index.php
/home/jd/Downloads/php-5.5.8/Zend/zend_API.c(1011) : Actual location (location was relayed)
```

Comment: Do you have php ZTS enabled? It is required for the use of threads (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.requirements.php). Command: --enable-maintainer-zts

Comment: Yes, I used this command:

./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads

Comment: Need to see the code ... also, I see no unknown class error ...

Comment: Sorry, I edited text and haven't change the title. PHP said that maybe I found a bug and I sent a report to thems.

Comment: I don't see the bug report, got a bug #?